# Crash on custom View in loadFromNib

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I have Checked all outlets and connections all seems fine.Can some one look into it and notice the fault, if any.Basically, this custom view is displayed over a view controller when user moves out of the specified region.

```
//  QMOutOfCountryView.m

 #import "QMOutOfCountryView.h"

 @implementation QMOutOfCountryView
 /*
 // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
 // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
     // Drawing code
 }
 */

 +(QMOutOfCountryView*)loadFromNib{
     NSArray *nibArr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QMOutOfCountryView" owner:self options:nil];
     QMOutOfCountryView *countryView;
     for (UIView * subview in nibArr) {
         if ([subview isKindOfClass:[QMOutOfCountryView class]]) {
             countryView = (QMOutOfCountryView *)subview;
             break;
         }
     }
     return countryView;
 }
 -(void)setdataOnViewWith:(int)viewType {
     if (viewType == location) {
         iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locationoff"];
         messageTextView.text = kLocationViewMessage;
     } else if (viewType == outOfCountry) {
         iconImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"illustration"];
         messageTextView.text = kOutOfCountryViewMessage;
     }
     messageTextView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     messageTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SFUIDisplay-Light" size:16.0f];
 }
 @end
```

Comment: what is the crash log says?

Comment: Show us your crash log?

Comment: Aside from showing the crash log, consider adding an exception breakpoint, which will point to the line that is forcing the crash. You can follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: NSArray *nibArr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"QMOutOfCountryView" owner:self options:nil];

this is the line which causing crash.

Comment: #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                objc_msgSend + 28
1  UIKit                          -[UINibStringIDTable dealloc] + 84
2  UIKit                          -[UINibDecoder dealloc] + 360
4  libobjc.A.dylib                object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
5  libobjc.A.dylib                objc_destructInstance + 92
6  libobjc.A.dylib                object_dispose + 28
7  libobjc.A.dylib                object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148

Comment: 8  libobjc.A.dylib  objc_destructInstance + 92
9  libobjc.A.dylib  object_dispose + 28
10 UIKit  -[UINib dealloc] + 176
11 UIKit -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 244
12 Q-municate +[QMOutOfCountryView loadFromNib] (QMOutOfCountryView.m:23)
13 Q-municate  -[QMDialogsViewController configureCountryView] (QMDialogsViewController.m:359)
14 Q-municate -[QMDialogsViewController viewDidLoad] (QMDialogsViewController.m:156)
15 UIKit -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
16 UIKit                          -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 72

Comment: Most important; this crash is not seen in development, it works fine. The crash is random.